# Jquery issue with popup window

Tags: jquery

I'm having an issue with the popup window showing the last element the user clicked on instead of the current element. I have several different coupons that the user can click on to print. If for example, the user clicks on the coupon with an id of "test", nothing happens but when the user clicks a second time, the coupon appears. In this case, the "test coupon" continues to appear no matter which coupon is clicked. If the page is manually refreshed, then the user can click on a new coupon. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(".coupon").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $('.pop').popupWindow({
        windowURL:'coupons/' + id + '.html'
    });
});
```

---

```
.coupon {
margin:10px;
height:152px;
width:193px;
position:relative;
cursor:pointer;
float:left;
}

.coupon .price {
margin-top:7px;
font-size:29px;
font-weight:bold;
color:white;
text-align:center;
}

.coupon .title {
margin-top:5px;
font-size:18px;
font-weight:bold;
color:black;
text-align:center;
font-family:'Times New Roman',Georgia,Serif;
}

<div class="coupon pop" id="test1">
  <div class="price">
    $5.00 OFF
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    Test
  </div>
</div>

<div class="coupon pop" id="test2">
  <div class="price">
    $5.00 OFF
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    Another test
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is popupWindow function doing ? are you using any plugins ?

Comment: Seems basically fine. Can you post your other code or a jsFiddle?

Comment: @Shyju, I'm using the plugin from here: http://www.swip.codylindley.com/popupWindowDemo.html

Comment: @j08691, I'm not familiar with how jsfiddle works.

Comment: When I alert the output of id, it is correct every time. It's just when the value of id is passed into the popupWindow that it doesn't give the right results.

Comment: @Muzz you will go to this location: http://jsfiddle.net/ put your code in relevant areas, select type of js you are using in right and click button run this will render the page in ouput area :)

Comment: @cpoDesign, thanks. I'll do that now. :)

Comment: @cpoDesign, here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/cYkKB/1 There may an issue though because I'm not sure how to incluse the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try this code and works

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('.coupon').each(function(){
    $(this).popupWindow({ 
        windowURL:$(this).attr("href")
    });
});
});
</script>
```

html code:

```
<a class="coupon" href="http://google.com" onclick="return false;" id="google">Google</a>
<a class="coupon" href="http://yahoo.com" onclick="return false;" id="yahoo">Yahoo</a>
```

Hope that the changes in attribute not broke your project

Chears

Update:
I convert your div tag into a

```
<a class="coupon" id="test1" href="_your_link_">
  <span class="price">$5.00 OFF</span>
  <span class="title">Test  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried this and it corrects having to click twice to bring up the new window however, now I only get the first coupon of 5 total listed in the HTML. I can't get any other coupons to come up.

Comment: Sure, I'll post it up top now. Thank you for having a look.

Comment: What it looks like to me is that the browser is caching the result of the click. It's really strange.

Comment: thanks. I've noticed that you're using the anchor tag to call the popup. In my example, I'm using the coupons id. I'm using `cursor:pointer` to show the user that they can click in the actual coupon to select it. Would this make any difference?

Comment: I converted your div into anchor I'm pretty sure that if you use div for active element older IE may cause a problems.

Comment: I think that you the styles will stay same just add `display:block` if you want spans to look like divs

Comment: Thank you awenart. I'm going to try this now. I'll be back and let you know if this works. Thank you again!

Comment: You sir, are the man! It worked well. I'll have to change some things around but it looks good. Thanks again!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10760/discussion-between-awenart-and-muzz)